How to use suction nozzle with wet saw?
I rented this Imer Combi 200VA wet saw from a local rental house. I noticed it comes with a suction nozzle that can be seen in the picture.

I have used wet saws before but they didn't come with a suction nozzle like that and were waterized only by the pan underneath. I just need to make one long rip of a stone threshold. What do I do with the suction nozzle here? I'm afraid to just dunk it in a bucket of water because of electricity going in.

It is probably an immersion pump, designed to be submerged (like a well pump). However it would be good to verify that first with the manual or rental house in case it is designed to mount to a try that is missing.

i couldn't find a manual online

This was in the top 5 results, and from the manufacturer website: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.imerusa.com/uploads/1/2/6/2/126204803/3226123_r07__2018_09__combi_200.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj_49KrtdKJAxV-j4kEHSgmATUQFnoECCgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3Ssd2vx6ZnZ6ci8utGVhGR. Not as explicit as you would want, but calls it an immersion pump.
